# How to override an environment variable in Github Actions?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

Given I have the following:

```
name: MyWorkFlow

on: push

env:
  FOO: bar1
jobs:
  myJob:
    - run: export FOO=bar2
    - run: echo $FOO
```

The output is 'bar1'. Is there anyway that I can override these environment variables?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
run: echo "FOO=1234" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```